# Category and subcategory tables in power bi matrix visualization

Tags: matrix, powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am looking for help to create a matrix visual in Power bi. I have several lookup and data tables.One of the sample table is

```
           Table
Name|Category|Sub-category|data
A   | Type1  | Sub1       | 3
A   | Type1  | Sub2       | 4
A   | Type1  | Sub3       | 3
A   | Type2  | Sub1       | 6
A   | Type2  | Sub2
A   | Type2  | Sub3
B
B
C
C
```

I am expecting an output matrix visual with categories and subcategories like below

Expected output matrix

```
           Type1   | Type2
Name|sub1|sub2|sub3|sub1|sub2
A.  | 3  | 4  | 3  | 6
B.  |    |
C
```

As of now, i was able to only create matrix with either category **or** sub category as columns and the other i used a slicer to filter. Another trial gave me the sub-category each into values or row. But expecting a multi-category table like I have shown. Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the Matrix as shown in the below image and then click on the red circled icon in your visual. This should solve your issue.

[image]